# Word 2013 template opens PowerPoint

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2013

When using Office Word 2013's new template home, I'm trying to apply a manuscript template that I found via the search bar (first option post-query). However, when I click the Create button it opens PowerPoint to the following page.

[image]

This happens with any theme I choose that isn't one of the defaults that Word ships with. I really want to be able to use templates, but man, if that's apparently not possible. Anyone know something about this?